# ¿Cómo convertir XML a Json con asp.net core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

hola comunidad quisiera saber si esto se puede realizar covertir un xml a json he estado buscando por Internet pero vienen ejemplos con cosas desactualizadas si me pudieran proporcionar un link o un ejemplo se los agradecería.
este es un ejemplo que encontré pero creo ya esta obsoleto:

```
string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' standalone='no'?>
<root>
  <person id='1'>
  <name>Alan</name>
  <url>http://www.google.com</url>
  </person>
  <person id='2'>
  <name>Louis</name>
  <url>http://www.yahoo.com</url>
  </person>
</root>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre que podrias deserializar el xml a una class y serializar luego esta a json

[C# Deserializing XML with namespace in .NET core](https://gotask.net/programming/deserializing-xml-with-namespace-in-c-sharp/)

entiendo que en net core quizas debas agregar la referencia usando nuget:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer
```

Entonces creas la clase en base al xml

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="person")]
public class Person {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="root")]
public class Root {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="person")]
    public List<Person> Person { get; set; }
}
```

quedando la deserializacion

```
string xmlStr = @"<?xml version='1.0' standalone='no'?>
                    <root>
                      <person id='1'>
                      <name>Alan</name>
                      <url>http://www.google.com</url>
                      </person>
                      <person id='2'>
                      <name>Louis</name>
                      <url>http://www.yahoo.com</url>
                      </person>
                    </root>";

var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlStr));
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
var root = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(ms);
```

Teniendo la deserializada del xml solo queda serializarla a json

[Try the new System.Text.Json APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/)

como usas `net core 3.1` puedes referenciar a `System.Text.Json` que es propia del framework no necesitas ninguna libreria de terceros

```
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.ToString<Root>(root);
```

Comment: ok muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya se por lo menos como empezar